# Algebra by Artin vs. Topics in Algebra by Herstein

Tags: reference-request, soft-question, book-recommendation

I am taking Abstract Algebra next semester and I would like to get a head start now. The assigned book for the class is Topics in Algebra by Herstein, but I have heard Algebra by Artin is superior.

Now just that information alone is enough to convince me to pick Artin, but I am on a time crunch here. I work full time and as a result I can never make it to the class. So I have to self study everything and because of full time work, I have to manage my time very well.

Keeping time management and efficiency in mind, should I ditch Herstein for Artin, or should I stick with the assigned textbook?

I am asking this because one can be more challenging or have more material than the other so it might take longer to get through the same topic than the other book.

PS: I know the topics that will be covered. And, I also own Algebra by Hungerford and Abstract Algebra by D&F in addition to Herstein and Artin.

Comment: Also my studying style is reading theorems, trying to prove them and studying their proofs thoroughly. I don't proceed until I fully understand the text.

Comment: I believe that Artin Abstract Algebra is a lot more difficult than Hestein's book. Artin uses a lot of geometry and linear algebra as motivation and if you liked your linear algebra course, you will probably enjoy Artin. However, speaking from experience, self-studying Artin Algebra is not easy  but certainly doable if you are motivated enough. Another problem with Artin is that some of the problems are trivial while the others are very involved (Herstien has better problems probably). That said, Artin's book is a very good introduction that allows you to jump straight to commutative algebra.